# Есть ли в русском языке слово «дененочно»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, грамматика, словообразование

Заметил, что некоторые авторы используют это слово, но в Викисловаре я его не нашёл.
Если такого слова нет, то что можно использовать максимально близкое по звучанию? А то «круглосуточно», по мне, звучит как-то угловато.

Answer (score 2):

Действительно, в словарях это слово пока не фиксируется. Максимально близкое по звучанию:

[**денно и нощно**](https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE_%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%BD%D0%BE)

> Устойчивое сочетание (фразеологизм). Используется в качестве наречия.
>
> *Да мы об вас, маменька, **денно и нощно** бога молим...* А. Н. Островский, «Гроза», 1860 г.
> *Да, я женился и во все время моей женатой жизни **денно и нощно** завидовал тому слизняку...* А. П. Чехов, «Мои жёны», 1885 г.

В Нацкорпусе русского языка «дененочно» тоже не встретилось, а вот «денно и нощно» – 497 раз.